# Can I use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") to detect a horizontal swipe in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect a horizontal swipe so the user can swipe left or right to toggle through a bunch of game characters. 1 left swipe toggles / displays the previous character and 1 right swipe toggles / displays the next character.

`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` will give me a range between -1 and 1 depending on if you swipe left or right.

If I add `Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"))` to `void update()` it prints out the axis range multiple times on every swipe / key press.

How can I get a single (the first) value `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` returns?

I want to do something like this:

```
void Update() {
 float swipe = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
 if (swipe > 0) {
  ToggleRight ();
 } else if (swipe < 0) {
  ToggleLeft();
 }
}
```

Is this possible or is there a way to implement horizontal swiping?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is that your function gets called during every game cycle while the swipe is in progress, your function ends up getting called multiple times. Basically, you want to have a way to filter the stream of update events and choose only the relevant ones.

One way you could do that is by using **Reactive Extensions**. You can download the unity-compatible version of reactive extensions [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/17276).

Once you've done that, you'll be able to translate unity input into an **observable stream**. Here is how you could do that:

```
using UnityEngine;

//  You'll need to include these namespaces.
using UniRx;
using System.Linq;
using System;

//  This will be responsible for converting unity input
//  into a stream of events.
public class SwipeListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    //  Rx Subjects allow you to create an observable stream of your
    //  own. You can push events to the stream by calling OnNext(). 
    private Subject<float> _subject;

    //  We'll expose the above stream via this property for a couple reasons.
    //  1) If we exposed the subject directly, other code could push events to
    //      our stream by calling OnNext(). Preventing that helps avoid bugs.
    //  2) We'll be filtering the stream to avoid having too many swipe-events.
    public IObservable<float> InputStream { get; private set; }

    //  Event values will be grouped by threes and averaged
    //  to smooth out noise.
    [SerializeField]
    private int _bufferCount = 3;

    //  Average displacement level below which no swipe event
    //  will be triggered.
    [SerializeField]
    private float _minimumThreshhold = 15;

    //  To prevent back-to-back swipe events. 
    [SerializeField]
    private float _slidingTimeoutWindowSeconds = .25f;

    private void Update()
    {
        //  We push values to our stream by calling OnNext() on our
        //  Subject in each game step. 
        _subject.OnNext(GetInputValue());
    }

    //  Here is where we get the value that will be pushed into the stream.
    //  For this demonstration, I'm using the mouse-position. You could easily
    //  override this and return touch positions instead.
    protected virtual float GetInputValue()
    {
        return Input.mousePosition.x;
    }

    public SwipeListener()
    {
        _subject = new Subject<float>();

        //  This is where the real magic happens. IObservable supports many of the
        //  same LINQ operations as IEnumerable.
        IObservable<float> filtered = _subject

            //  Convert stream of horizontal mouse positions into a stream of 
            //  mouse speed values.
            .Pairwise()
            .Select(x => x.Current - x.Previous)

            //  Group events and average them to smooth out noise. The group size
            //  can be configured in the inspector.
            .Buffer(_bufferCount)
            .Select(x => x.Average())

            //  Filter out events if the mouse was not moving quickly enough. This
            //  can be configured in the inspector. You'll want to play around with this.
            .Where(x => Mathf.Abs(x) > _minimumThreshhold);

        //  Now we'll apply a sliding timeout window to throttle our stream. this
        //  will help prevent multiple back-to-back swipe events when you swipe once.
        //  I've split the event stream into two separate streams so we can throttle
        //  left and right swipes separately. This will help ensure that there isn't 
        //  unnecessary lag when swiping left after having swiped right, or vice-versa.

        TimeSpan seconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_slidingTimeoutWindowSeconds);
        IObservable<float> left = filtered
            .Where(x => x < 0)
            .Throttle(seconds);

        IObservable<float> right = filtered
            .Where(x => x > 0)
            .Throttle(seconds);

        //  Now that we've throttled left and right swipes separately, we can merge 
        //  them back into a single stream. 
        InputStream = left.Merge(right);
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is write a script that consumes the above script. Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UniRx;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(SwipeListener))]
public class ColorFlasher : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Material _left;

    [SerializeField]
    private Material _right;

    private Material _normal;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _flashPeriod = .1f;

    private MeshRenderer _meshRenderer;

    private SwipeListener _inputListener;

    void Start()
    {
        _meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        _normal = _meshRenderer.material;

        _inputListener = GetComponent<SwipeListener>();
        _inputListener.InputStream
            .Subscribe(x => StartCoroutine(FlashColor(x)));
        _inputListener.InputStream.Subscribe(x => Debug.Log(x));
    }

    private IEnumerator FlashColor(float swipe)
    {
        Material material = _normal;

        if (swipe > 0)
            material = _right;
        else if (swipe < 0)
            material = _left;

        _meshRenderer.material = material;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_flashPeriod);

        _meshRenderer.material = _normal;
    }
}
```

The above script simply has a cube that flashes a different color briefly whenever a swipe is detected.

A complete version of the above example is available on [on my github](https://github.com/NewellClark/StackOverflow_DetectSwipeUnity3D).